# Best way to get Polarion data and store to different database

Tags: java, polarion

My requirement is to get polarion data and store that to our sql server database.
I went through Polarion SDK document and I feel webservice is the way to do that....
Which is the best way to read and store specific data from polarion to SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

The webservice is very slow and depending on your size it will not be practicable to export your data with help of the webservice.
However the data in Polarion is stored in an SVN-repository in form of small .xml-files. So you can read these XML files directly from the repository.

As Polarion is not stored in a database compatible format, you need to setup your own DB-schema and the transform from the XML-files should be straight forward.

You can either checkout a complete Polarion Project or you retrieve the files on demand via http(s) second approach will be slightly slower again.